# Node.js MongoDB - How to update multiple documents with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a `users` collection and every `user` has a number of contacts. When a `user` deletes their account I want that this user's id would be deleted from the contacts array of all the users with who this user is connected. I have tried this `Model.Update` query but it doesn't work. Here is my code so far:

```
                User.update({'userId':{ $in: userIds }, 
                        $pullAll: {'contacts': [myId] },'multi': true 
                    },function(err, count) {
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        }else{
                            console.log(count);
                        } 
                    });
```

Comment: I take it that `userIds` is an array of id's for users that need to be removed and subsequently remove them from the `contacts` array of the other users, correct? Can you also update your question to show the `User` model's schema definition?

Comment: @chridam yes, correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The update document and `multi` should be passed as separate arguments:

```
User.update({
  userId : { $in : userIds }        // conditions
}, {
  $pullAll : { contacts : [myId] }  // document
}, {
  multi : true                      // options
}, function(err, count) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(count);
  }
});
```

Documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update).

Answer (score 0):

Can update multiple documents with multiple conditions

```
Model.update({
    _id : { $in : ids}        // conditions
}, {
    $set: {deletion_indicator: constants.N} // document
}, {
    multi : true                      // options
}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```